# How can I identify the client of my service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, wcf-security

I want to create a new WCF service and client. The 2 parties will communicate using 2 way SSL, in order to trust each other.

My question is how, at the server's side, can I identify who is the client that works against it. The best thing will be to achieve the client's certificate (which was sent during the authentication phase of SSL).

I need this certificate in order to give this client permissions depending of who is it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current
```

to check its proeprties:

- AuthorizationPolicies
- IsAnonymous
- PrimaryIdentity
- WindowsIdentity

Comment: And where Can I find the client's certificate? Is it the PrimaryIdentity?

Comment: @MattanLevy: `ServiceSecurityContext.Current
.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets`